# How to decide when to use inheritance or just use the functionality of the base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have some question about the concept of inheritance in OOP. When I just finished coding of the custom class to connect the database.
 e.g.

```
   `// for encapsulate some method under and use as the team's custom 
    // version of DBconnect
   public class DBconnector()
   {
      public void SetConnection(); // setting 
      public void BeginCon(); // setting 
      public void SetQuery(String i_Query , CommandType cmdType); // setting 
      public Object GetExcetue();
     ... // other setting 
   }`
```

Then The system has the separate business logic classed that will get the content(data from DB) for its module like BusinessLogicM1 , BusinessLogicM2 , BusinessLogicM3...
   These separate classed will get the data from Db by use of functionality from DBconnector. So I am confuse here whether I should coding the BusinessLogic classes by inherit from the DBconnector class of just use the methods of DBconnector.
       `public class BusinessLogicX :DBconnector 
       { 
            public Object GetXData()
            { 
                ...// setting 
                return this.GetExcetue();
            }
       }`
         or
       `public class BusinessLogicX
        { 
            public Object GetXData()
            { 
                var service = new DBconnector();
                ...//setting
                return service.GetExcetue();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if BusinessLogicX class is intent to query the data of its module from
>   DB, is it not mean that the BusinessLogicX class has the same
>   functionality of DBConnector ( that it can connect to the DB) ?

No. That's not correct and inheritance is out of question between BL (business logic) and DB (storage).

**Separation of Concerns**:

Your business class just needs the data and should not be concerned about the mechanism to retrieve it. In fact it should not even know whether data is retrieved from MSSQL, Oracle or simply a file based data source. That's all headache of data access layer or classes. When you go to coffee shop, all that matters to you is a cup of coffee you ordered for, and not how they prepared it!

As @milindmb pointed out correctly, you should put common behavior in base BL, if applicable. You can mark base BL as `abstract` instead of concrete.

**DbConnector**:

I would suggest defining an `interface` for this and inject it's implementation in BL class as a dependency. Note that Interfaces are not mandatory for dependency injection. You can have class type be injected as well as shown in @milinmb's base BL class. Interfaces have added advantage that they can be mocked if/when you are unit testing business logic classes. That's another story. So typically your business class would look something like below (I like to call them services. It's your choice):

```
public abstract class ServiceBase {
    protected readonly IDbConnector dbConnector;

    public ServiceBase(IDbConnector dbConnector) {
        this.dbConnector = dbConnector;
    }
}

public class UserService : ServiceBase {
    public UserService(IDbConnector dbConnector) : base(dbConnector) {
    }

    // use dbConnector from ServiceBase 
}
```

Having `IDBConnector` will mean, in future you will be able to inject it's different implementation base on data source you are using, eg: SqlConnector, OracleConnector etc. Above shows the constructor injection, and that's one type dependency injection (DI). There are method and setter (using properties) injection as well. Because sometimes dependencies are optional and you may want to create class instances without injecting them. Learn more about DI.

**Repositories**:

This is going to be beyond the scope, so I leave this to you for study. Check Google for using repositories that form data access layer of your application. Their usage depends on the scope of your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarify @milindmb 's answer and point out where my perspective is gone wrong. And  could you further explain about  " Interfaces have added advantage that they can be mocked". I mean if the service class have injected the Dbconnector class (and not defining the interface ),can't service class be tested or something?

Comment: Please read online for that stuff. There's plenty of material available and people have been doing it since ages. You can start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance should be driven based on the intended functionality of the classes. In your case functionality of DBConnector class is to manage database connection/Queries and that of BusinessLogicX class is to implement business logic. Thus these 2 classes are not related hence should not have inheritance.
I suggest you can should just use methods of DBConnector class.

In your BusinessLogic implementation if BusinessLogicM1 , BusinessLogicM2.. share any common behavior, then you should build inheritance as

```
class BaseBusinessLogic
{
    public void commonMethod1() 
    {
    }
    public void commonMethod2() 
    {
    }

    public Object GetXData()
    { 
            var service = new DBconnector();
            ...//setting
            return service.GetExcetue();
    }
}


Class BusinessLogicM1 : BaseBusinessLogic
{
      public void M1LogicMethod()
      {
          ..........
      }
}
```

You can also think of making DBConnector as member of BaseBusinessLog class, thus maintaining database connections can be at one place.

... Example of BaseBusinessLogic class having DBConnector as member

```
class BaseBusinessLogic
{

    private DBconnector _connector;

    public void initConnector( DBConnector iConnector)
    {
        this._connector =  iConnector;
    }

    public void commonMethod1() 
    {
    }
    public void commonMethod2() 
    {
    }

    public Object GetXData()
   { 

            ...//setting
            _connector.SetQuery("..."); // Query to get 'X' Data
            return _connector.GetExcetue();
    }
}


Class BusinessLogicM1 : BaseBusinessLogic
{
      public void M1LogicMethod()
      {
          // Fetch DataList from DBConnector
          _connector.SetQuery(".....");
          Object obj = _connector.GetExecute();

          Object xData = GetXData();

          // use obj and xData Object to build BusinessLogicM1
      }
}
```

Comment: And what if BusinessLogicX class is intent to query the data of its module  from DB, is it not mean that the BusinessLogicX class has the same functionality of DBConnector ( that it can connect  to the DB) ?
I think the businessLogicX class is relate to DBConnector class , because it must have and ability to retrieve data from DB.
Or maybe I just misinterpret/misunderstand things from the start?

Comment: If you build inheritance for BusinessLogicX classes, then as I wrote earlier, BaseBusinessLogic class can have DBConnector object as member variable, which can be used by all the subClasses to Query the Database . ( Adding example in another answer below)